# Visual Studio. markup template engines script's type

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, handlebars.js, template-engine, underscore.js-templating

I would like to ask where could I find the whole list of supported highlighting feature for template engines like *underscorejs*, *handlebarsjs*, *mustache.js*, etc...

For example, I noticed that *handlebarsjs* highlighting turns on when I set *script*'s tag **type** attribute to: `text/x-handlebars`

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
a lot of WebEssentials stuff becomes a part of VS/Web Tools. I found *CommonHTMLTypes.xsd* file in VS schemas folder (*Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Schemas\1033\HTML*) where you can see what is supported for **script** tag:

`<xsd:simpleType name="scriptTypeType">
        <xsd:union>
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/javascript" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/html" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/ng-template" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/x-handlebars" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/x-handlebars-template" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/x-jsrender" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/template" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="text/x-jquery-tmpl" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:union>
    </xsd:simpleType>`

Strange enough, but I don't have this file registered in my VS by default and that's why I don't get IntelliSense popup for the **type** attribute with all these variants

Comment: were you looking for more than the docs http://vswebessentials.com/features/html? I am not aware of a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about Web Essentials [**feature**](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3588819-provide-syntax-highlighting-for-html-within-templa). Here's a few other related [**topics**](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/search?filter=merged&query=templates).